# Using front controller pattern in struts and spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, struts

Struts and Spring MVC uses Front controller pattern, so if I want to develop an application using any one of these frameworks then the server creates multiple threads to support multiple user requests.

So if my application is used by thousands of users at a given point of time then will the server will be able to serve the application by creating so many threads without any issues?

Is there any limit for number of threads created by any application server? Will there be any scalability issues that we face? I tried to search in internet but I have not found proper results, please help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

From Framework point of view, there are no restrictions . but for sure each app server will have property to configure / set default max number of threads per Application ( war /ear) . And In modern App Servers running in clusters which can be scale based on number of managed servers has. Max Thread count should be based on number of CPU and the Operations the thread does.